# Initialize embedded struct in Go

Tags: struct, go

I have the following `struct` which contains a `net/http.Request`:

```
type MyRequest struct {
    http.Request
    PathParams map[string]string
}
```

Now I want to initialize the anonymous inner struct `http.Request` in the following function:

```
func New(origRequest *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) *MyRequest {
    req := new(MyRequest)
    req.PathParams = pathParams
    return req
}
```

How can I initialize the inner struct with the parameter `origRequest`?

Comment: This example shows another way 
recommended https://play.golang.org/p/Gbn8e6CTVi_c

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What about:

```
func New(origRequest *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) *MyRequest {
        return &MyRequest{*origRequest, pathParams}
}
```

It shows that instead of

```
New(foo, bar)
```

you might prefer just

```
&MyRequest{*foo, bar}
```

directly.

Comment: How about when there is some field you don't want to initialize yourself, e.g., a file of type sync.Mutex?

Comment: The zero value of a mutex should be a ready-to-use mutex, so you're good simply including it as an embedded value:

`var hits struct {
    sync.Mutex
    n int
}

hits.Lock()
hits.n++
hits.Unlock()`

(from [10 things you probably didn't know about Go](https://talks.golang.org/2012/10things.slide#3))

Answer (score 44):

```
req := new(MyRequest)
req.PathParams = pathParams
req.Request = origRequest
```

or...

```
req := &MyRequest{
  PathParams: pathParams
  Request: origRequest
}
```

See: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types for more about embedding and how the fields get named.

Comment: I get the compiler error `cannot use origRequest (type *http.Request) as type http.Request in assignment`. I guess this is because `Request` is not a named field.

Comment: nope it's because the type of the field is not the same as the type of origRequest. Use *origRequest instead and the problem goes away.

Comment: You're right: derefencing with the asterisk or using a reference in the struct helps. Thanks.

Comment: As for how the fields get named: "The unqualified type name acts as the field name." So `http.Request` ends up being called just `Request`.

Answer (score 7):

As Jeremy shows above, the "name" of an anonymous field is the same as the type of the field. So if the value of x were a struct containing an anonymous int, then x.int would refer to that field.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness sake, I'll add another example as well. Based on the comment from @Victor

> This example shows another way recommended https://play.golang.org/p/Gbn8e6CTVi_c

```
type MyRequest struct {
    http.Request
    PathParams map[string]string
}

func New(origRequest *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) *MyRequest {
    req := MyRequest{Request: origRequest, PathParams: pathParams}
    return req
}
```

Another comment from @Jeffery Martinez helped clarify it further:

> As for how the fields get named: "The unqualified type name acts as the field name." So `http.Request` ends up being called just `Request`

i.e: The two following declarations are equivalent

```
// Version 1
type MyRequest struct {
    http.Request
    PathParams map[string]string
}

// Version 2
type MyRequest struct {
    Request http.Request
    PathParams map[string]string
}
```